# Como posso refazer a conexão com o banco de dados colocando as variáveis no standalone em vez de por no código Java

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, eclipse, jax-ws

Preciso incluir as variáveis *urlLot*, *user* e *pass* no *standalone* para não precisar mudar o código e recompilar todas vez que eu trocar de ambiente. Infelizmente não consigo pensar em nenhuma maneira de fazer isso sem ter que mudar toda a estrutura do projeto.

Segue como está minha classe de conexão com o banco de dados:

```
public Connection getConexao() throws SQLException{
        String urlLot = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/teste";
        String user      =  "postgres";
        String pass      =  "123";

        try {           
            if(this.connection == null || this.connection.isClosed()){
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");             
                this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlLot, user, pass);     
                PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("set search_path=db_teste;"); 
                s.execute();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi planeja usar o wildfly ou jboss, dando a ele a responsabilidade de sua conexao, nesse caso você precisa:

1. **Configurar o servidor de aplicação**: no link a seguir explico como fazer isso no wildfly para uma conexao usando oracle: https://medium.com/@fmotta.antonio/configurando-datasource-oracle-no-wildfly-13f382d4bb3d
2. Preparar sua aplicação para que a mesma use JTA, isso é feito via JPA, logo você precisa entender como aplicar JPA na sua aplicação de preferencia usando hibernate, um tutorial bem bacana de como fazer isso pode ser encontrado no link a seguir:https://blog.algaworks.com/tutorial-jpa/ e https://www.devmedia.com.br/jpa-e-hibernate-acessando-dados-em-aplicacoes-java/32711
3. Por fim, o pulo do gato que é **passar a responsabilidade da conexão para o servidor de aplicação**: Os tutoriais acima te ensina a criar um persistence com RESOURCE_LOCAL, ou seja, você ainda permanece colocando as configurações de banco na aplicação, para passar essa responsabilidade para o servidor basta mudar a seguinte configuração no persistence:

```
<persistence-unit name="nomeDaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
```

para JTA, e acrescentar a propriedade `jta-data-source`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="nomeDaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/nomeDoDataSourceConfiguradoNoServidor</jta-data-source>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Sugiro que faça passo a passo em forma de PoC (prova de conceito), implemente o JPA usando RESOURCE_LOCAL, depois tente passar a responsabilidade para o servidor de aplicação.